# How to get Unique Log on & Log off event in windows

Tags: login, windows-event-log, logoff

I want to get unique logon & log off event from my pc.
In the event viewer i can see more then one entry for login & log out event.
I check most of the event details but could not found unique event for logged in by user.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bf1f69599d.gif

Answer (score 1):

Your logon events *are* unique. You're just not looking at the unique data.

Each event with ID 4624 will contain, in the description, a logon ID (and, if it's a domain logon, a logon GUID), username, and a raft of other detail information.

To correlate a logoff event (event ID 4634) with a logon, you'll need to examine the description of the logoff event and correlate the logon ID there with the logon IDs logged when logon events occur.